# Parse Linkedin API call

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, linkedin-api

Here is what it looks like in the Mainviewcontroller.

I have two separate classes, LinkedInUser and _User. The accessToken is stored in the LinkedInUser not in the _User. There is a pointer in the LinkedInUser class called "user" which points to the "objectID" in _User. I want to retrieve the accessToken from LinkedInUser but overtime I try a query it returns no results and when I run the code below, it results in a null. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
  [PFLinkedInUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"User: %@, Error: %@", user, error);

    PFObject *linkedin = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"LinkedInUser"];

    NSString *accessToken = linkedin[@"accessToken"];

        [PFLinkedInUtils.linkedInHttpClient GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(blahblahblah)?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
PFObject *linkedin = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"LinkedInUser"];
```

is creating a new instance of a `LinkedInUser` object. It will not have a value for the `accessToken` property. Instead you should query Parse for the existing object associated with the user.

Additionally, if you are able to change your data model slightly, it might be better to have a pointer on `_User` that references the `LinkedInUser`. That way, you can just get that object directly without having to make another query.